# Pyinstaller Exe generation without TensorFlow

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

i need to create a exe file from my python code. 
i use tensorflow and using the pyinstaller but i have a huge file exe.

Can i create a small portable exe without the dependencies of my code?

Comment: May I know how you did that? pyinstaller does not even include the Tensorflow in the exe for me! So I have "ImportError: No module named tensorflow" when running the executable!

Comment: yes you can create